# How to add means of each x level in a regression plot?

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting a linear regression fit for the Loblolly data in R and trying to add each mean y for each x level. My code is below:

```
 plot(Loblolly$height~Loblolly$age, xlab = "Age", ylab = "Height", main = "Loblolly Data")
    lob.fit <- lm(Loblolly$height~Loblolly$age)
    lob.sum <- summary(lob.fit)
    str(lob.sum)
    abline(lob.fit)
```

This is probably a really easy question with a really easy answer but I don't know how to add the means. When I google all that shows up is ggplot and I'm not supposed to be using that. Any help?

Comment: calculate the mean for each level first for both x and y (`aggregate` or `tapply` can be used). You will then have the (x,y) points that you can plot using `points` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @AndroMine stated in comments, you could use `aggregate` in `points` to get the means. Choose a nice `pch=` such as `"-"`, give it a `col=`or and increase the size of the `cex=`.  Note that the functions you use have a `data=` argument, so you don't have to keep typing `Loblolly$`.

```
plot(height ~ age, Loblolly, xlab="Age", ylab="Height", main="Loblolly Data")
abline(lm(height ~ age, Loblolly))
points(aggregate(height ~ age, Loblolly, mean), pch='-', cex=4, col=4)
```

[image]